# Finding local minima and local maxima

Tags: matlab, vector, linear-algebra

I would like to find local minima and local maxima of a given vector. Let's assume that the given vector is as follow:

```
speed =

0.0002
0.0008
0.0014
0.0027
0.0037
0.0047
0.0054
0.0053
0.0053
0.0058
0.0060
0.0063
0.0062
0.0065
0.0062
0.0061
0.0060
0.0057
0.0062
0.0057
0.0053
0.0050
0.0047
0.0065
0.0049
0.0048
0.0033
0.0033
0.0041
0.0049
0.0063
0.0075
0.0085
0.0105
0.0108
0.0109
0.0105
0.0105
0.0099
0.0098
0.0099
0.0099
0.0105
0.0103
0.0112
0.0108
0.0088
0.0079
0.0066
0.0055
0.0058
0.0049
0.0049
0.0055
0.0060
0.0051
0.0055
0.0060
0.0053
0.0047
0.0058
0.0050
0.0044
0.0033
0.0022
0.0008
0.0015
0.0010
0.0011
0.0024
0.0028
0.0024
0.0016
0.0009
0.0009
0.0009
0.0015
0.0015
0.0025
0.0031
0.0030
0.0042
0.0051
0.0060
0.0065
0.0054
0.0012
0.0043
0.0059
0.0070
0.0078
0.0076
0.0082
0.0087
0.0088
0.0095
0.0101
0.0100
0.0110
0.0103
0.0111
0.0120
0.0118
0.0116
0.0115
0.0121
0.0120
0.0145
0.0107
0.0119
0.0110
0.0116
0.0102
0.0086
0.0076
0.0071
0.0055
0.0066
0.0063
0.0077
0.0052
0.0059
0.0061
0.0036
0.0047
0.0053
0.0027
0.0020
0.0011
0.0041
0.0034
0.0034
0.0019
0.0022
0.0008
0.0001
0.0007
0.0009
0.0010
0.0010
0.0001
0.0007
0.0014
0.0016
0.0016
0.0013
0.0008
0.0008
0.0005
0.0004
0.0002
0.0001
0.0004
0.0005
0.0006
0.0005
0.0006
0.0006
0.0004
0.0002
0.0000
0.0001
0.0001
0.0002
0.0003
0.0004
0.0004
0.0005
0.0007
0.0008
0.0007
0.0006
0.0005
0.0006
0.0006
0.0004
0.0002
0.0003
0.0006
0.0005
0.0005
0.0010
0.0012
0.0014
0.0020
0.0028
0.0039
0.0044
0.0061
0.0074
0.0082
0.0091
0.0102
0.0108
0.0110
0.0117
0.0128
0.0133
0.0148
0.0153
0.0155
0.0150
0.0146
0.0137
0.0130
0.0113
0.0110
0.0107
0.0112
0.0114
0.0113
0.0104
0.0101
0.0095
0.0088
0.0083
0.0076
0.0057
0.0047
0.0043
0.0046
0.0053
0.0063
0.0078
0.0070
0.0062
0.0053
0.0051
0.0055
0.0048
0.0053
0.0052
0.0055
0.0065
0.0075
0.0078
0.0081
0.0067
0.0044
0.0061
0.0047
0.0032
0.0033
0.0028
0.0019
0.0007
0.0017
0.0016
0.0025
0.0034
0.0037
0.0044
0.0039
0.0037
0.0029
0.0030
0.0025
0.0022
0.0025
0.0027
0.0028
0.0031
0.0029
0.0025
0.0025
0.0025
0.0024
0.0022
0.0021
0.0019
0.0020
0.0020
0.0016
0.0016
0.0015
0.0013
0.0011
0.0011
0.0010
0.0009
0.0008
0.0006
0.0005
0.0004
0.0002
0.0000
0.0002
0.0003
0.0004
0.0006
0.0005
0.0004
0.0003
0.0004
0.0003
0.0003
0.0004
0.0006
0.0004
0.0004
```

when I polt this vector in Matlab using command `plot(speed)` then I have the following figure:

[image: illustration]

How could I find the maxima and minima's of the given vector? For example, in this above picture my aim is to find the three minimums/maximums that are shown in the picture. 
I have lots of such a vectors that I want to write a code for all to find local minimas and maximas as well.

Comment: If you want local minima, just seach for maxima of `-speed`

Comment: Thanks. But why search for maxima when I want to find local minima?

Comment: because `findpeaks` only finds maxima, but you can use the power of mathematics to still get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define what you count as extremum (maximum or minimum), i.e. which scale is considered appropriate, as your curve in reality has much more local maxima and minima than 3 or 4. Therefore looking for zero-crossings of the first derivative with `diff` will give you a lots of spurious micro-peaks. One option is to smooth it before. However, it might be easier to resort to a standard tool.

Try [`findpeaks`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) from Signal Processing Toolbox.

There you can specify the scale with various parameters, such as `'MinPeakDistance'`, `'MinPeakHeight'`, `'Threshold'` etc.